# Change working directory of console in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console

How do I change the default working directory when I open a new Python Console? I have multiple projects open in my PyCharm view and the Python Console seems to be defaulting to an arbitrary one. Of course I can work around by modifying `sys.path` but I want a definite solution. Using Windows.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Settings → Build Execution Deployment → Console → Python Console

Comment: I did this and refreshed/restarted the console. No luck. However, when I restarted the entire pycharm app it worked.

Comment: Worked after refreshing the `Python Console` and  `Terminal`.