# Python console pointing to the wrong project directory

Tags: python, console, pycharm

Not sure if this is the right forum for the question

I am running python 3.6 on pycharm. I have multiple projects and when I open a script from say "project_aa" and try and run it on the pycharm console, it doesn't link to that project directory. For instance assuming I have another project called "project_bb", this is what I see when I run script from project_aa

```
C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\envs\PA36\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=53049
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\abc\\PycharmProjects\\project_bb', 'C:/Users/abc/PycharmProjects/project_bb'])
```

in short a wrong path is linked. What seems to be going wrong here? and is it possible to manually change the path on the console to link to the correct project i.e. "project_aa"

Comment: What do you mean with "PyCharm console"? The terminal? Why do you use the terminal to run programs in PyCharm? Terminal doesn't know anything about your program, and you may activate your environment (just exec python from env is often not enough) What it is your real problem?

Comment: thats the problem, and got the solution as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818938/pycharm-change-working-directory-of-console